# How to Improve rigid registration for 2D images

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image, simpleitk, image-registration

I am looking for a way to improve the rigid registration procedure of 2D images and evaluate metrics for better rigid registration using SimpleITK, here is my code

```
import SimpleITK as sitk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
moving_Image = sitk.ReadImage("mri_2d_moving.tif")
fixed_Image = sitk.ReadImage('mri_structural_2d.tif')
movingImageArray=sitk.GetArrayFromImage(moving_Image)
fixedImageArray=sitk.GetArrayFromImage(fixed_Image)
plt.imshow(movingImageArray,cmap='Greens', vmin=0, vmax=255)
plt.imshow(fixedImageArray, alpha=0.5,cmap='Oranges', vmin=0, vmax=255)

elastixImageFilter = sitk.ElastixImageFilter()
registration_method= sitk.ImageRegistrationMethod()
elastixImageFilter.SetFixedImage(fixed_Image)
elastixImageFilter.SetMovingImage(moving_Image)
elastixImageFilter.SetParameterMap(sitk.GetDefaultParameterMap("rigid"))
elastixImageFilter.Execute()
outputImage=elastixImageFilter.GetResultImage()
outputImageArray=sitk.GetArrayFromImage(outputImage)
plt.imshow(outputImageArray,cmap='Greens', vmin=0, vmax=255)
plt.imshow(fixedImageArray, alpha=0.5,cmap='Oranges', vmin=0, vmax=255)
```

The registration is terrible along the edges how can I change the parameters to improve registration, any suggestions are welcome

Imaging data can be downloaded from the below links

[moving image](https://imgur.com/YIueB43)
[fixed image](https://imgur.com/WE7GaqO)

Comment: data please. [mre]

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I have provided the data for your reference, please check it

Comment: same question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77145837/improving-affine-registration-with-changing-parameters

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, No there are a few changes in the parameters and interpolation method I used.